# How to fix the columns size in different screen resolutions using vuetify grid

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating a simple dashboard using Vue and Veutify. I choose to structure the layout using the grid system available in vuetify's library. The problem is that I can't get the same look depending on the screen resolution. 
Is there any way to have the left container always with the width of the  side drawer?

I already try to set the max-width of the side bar manually in 300px, but did'nt work.

```
<v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs3 class="side">
        <SideBar/>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs9 class="main" >
         <MainPage/>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
```

I expect

[image]

I got

[image]

edit: HTML/CSS generated: https://pastebin.com/bLYgv5pz

Comment: If you can post the rendered HTML and CSS, that would make it a lot easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the 3-column area is designed to always be 25% of the container width for grids like this.  If you want to keep the sidebar the size of the 3-column section, you can give it `max-width:100%;`

I'm not familiar with the exact styling used by Vuetify, but if you can post the generated HTML and CSS, it should certainly be possible to suggest how you might restrict the growth of that column.